# Any idiom in English for a husband who has been betrayed by his wife?

Tags: idioms

Is there any idiom in English for a husband who has been betrayed by his wife? (I mean she slept and is occasionally still sleeping with her lover). Or maybe not an idiomatic expression, but just one word that is commonly used for such a person?

Comment: Well, you've been given *cuckold*, but that's a really dated term. People would probably think you were really odd if you used it in earnest today - it's strange diction *and* a strange way to talk about another person's private life in today's society. In fact, I don't think there even *is* any more up-to-date equivalent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A *[cuckold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckold)* is

> a historically derogatory term for **a man who has an unfaithful wife**.
>   The word, which has been in recorded use since the 13th century,
>   derives from the cuckoo bird, some varieties of which lay their eggs
>   in other birds' nests.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cuckold) offers the following:

> mid-13c., kukewald, from O.Fr. cucuault, from cocu (see cuckoo) +
>   pejorative suffix -ault, of Germanic origin. So called from the female
>   bird's alleged habit of changing mates, or her authentic habit of
>   leaving eggs in another bird's nest. The verb is 1580s, from the noun.
>   Related: Cuckolded; cuckolding; cuckoldry.

**Edit**: [This part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckold#Cultural_usage_of_horn_metaphor) of the Wikipedia article covers the variations on the 'horn' metaphor (to put the horns on, &c).

Comment: @dmckee Is that so?  I never heard that idiom.  Is it British?  American?

Comment: @Pitarou, see my edit.

Comment: @dmckee: Oh please! That sort of expression belongs to Shakespeare's day, not the modern era!

Comment: In Greek the formal word is "απατημένος (σύζυγος)" ("cheated (husband)") and the most common informal is "κερατάς" (horned one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard Americans use "He's wearin' horns"; it's strange how some phrases last so long while others vanish.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: Well, I guess most educated people would *understand* the expression, but it surprises me if you've heard more than one person *actually say it* non-facetiously. Are you sure you haven't just misconstrued [the more likely modern usage](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+if+he%27s+wearing+horns%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - typically something like *"They looked at him like he was wearing horns"* (i.e. - like they thought he was the Devil incarnate)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers My people, the rednecks and hillbillies as we are called, retain many an archaic expression and have coined a few colorful ones as well.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: I must stand corrected then. But I'll leave my first comment there, because I think in most contexts native English speakers would look askance if you just came out with that one. There are still regions in the UK where it's not uncommon to hear *"thou"* instead of *"you"*, for example. But it's mainly older speakers even there - a young person using such forms in London would really stick out, and probably be ridiculed if he wasn't obviously doing it facetiously.

Comment: In modern usage, it also refers to a sexual sub-culture where men enjoy their wives having sexual relations with other people. Strictly such men aren't cuckolds, because they aren't betrayed, though power-play within the scene in question complicates this, often with the woman and/or her lover in the dominant position (and the husband enjoying the submissive position of being "unable" to compete) but also in the oxymoronic "dominant cuckold". This sense is still rare, but can complicate modern use.

Answer (score 1):

If the man is not the father of his children, we might say he has a cuckoo in the nest.

(A cuckoo is a bird that lays its eggs in the nest of another species, and leaves them to raise its chicks.)

Comment: I think that's more of a French idiom: I've not heard it in English (though the meaning is obvious).

Answer (score 1):

*Victim of adultery* seems to be a common legal term for the spouse who isn't the perpetrator. It is also a popular term in Christian counseling circles.

Or you could just say he is *the betrayed*.